# How can I configure React router correctly to navigate to a new page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a navbar containing 3 Anchors, I want to navigate between different pages when clicking on each one.
I've used `react-router` (version 6.3.0) to achieve this but I faced two issues and I got a stack.

The first one is when I click on a **LaunchApp** anchor, the URL change to `http://localhost:3000/launchApp` the page shows its content but on the top of the home page, not on a new page.
The second one is when I refresh the page, the page doesn't go back to the home page (`http://localhost:3000`) but it renders the last anchor I clicked on.

**App.js**

```
return (
  <s.Main>
    <>  
      <Navbar/>
      <HeroSection/>
      <About/>
      <Testimonials/>
      <ContactForm/>
      <Footer/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HeroSection/>}/>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
        <Route path="/launchApp" element={<LaunchApp />}>
        <Route path="submitSubscription" 
                element={<SubmitSubscription/>}/>
        <Route path="CancelSubscription" 
                element={<CancelSubscription />}/>
        </Route>
      </Routes> 
    </>
  </s.Main>
);
```

**Navbar return**

```
return (
  <nav> 
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/launchApp">Launch App</Link>     
      </li>      
    </ul>
  </nav>
)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering several components twice, once unconditionally in the `App`, and then again conditionally in a route. If I'm understanding correctly, you don't want the routed content to duplicate the main page content.

Remove the duplicate components not on a route and move the routes up between the `Navbar` and `Footer` components.

Example:

```
return (
  <s.Main>
    <Navbar/>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<HeroSection />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="/launchApp" element={<LaunchApp />} />
    </Routes>
    <Testimonials/>
    <ContactForm/>
    <Footer/>
  </s.Main>
);
```

To handle redirecting back to the "main" page on a page load, use the `useNavigation` hooks to redirect in a mounting `useEffect` hook in the app component.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  }, []); // note *

  return (
    <s.Main> ... </s.Main>
  );
};
```

** The linter may complain about missing dependency navigate, it's a stable reference and is safe to add.*

Comment: It's worked for navigating between different routers on the same page like (Home, about) but when I clicked on LaunchApp the problem persists, then I have the content of this page on the top of the about page. When clicking on the Launch page I would like to render sublinks components and their contents the same concepts as https://uniswap.org/ but inside the same domain name (edited my post). thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @DavidJay That "launch app" button appears to link to a completely different page. In your code example though, `"/launchApp"` is a local route so it should work the same as the other routes. Can you clarify more precisely what the issue is?

Comment: When I clicked on "launch app" what I expect is to get a new page with its own content. For example on  uniswap.org when clicking on the "launch app" button it takes the user to a new page. The issue that I got was the content of launchApp component renders on the top of the home page content, even though the URL is http://localhost:3000/launchApp

Comment: @DavidJay I don't understand what "renders on the top of the home page content" means, but if you are wanting to open a new page/app/etc with its content then you need to use a regular anchor tag (`<a />`) to link to the external links since `react-router-dom` only handles routing/navigation within the same React app, i.e. internal links.

Comment: I got the concept! It worked!! Thanks again for your efforts.